# Convex hull and convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{c_n\}$ be sequences of complex numbers and suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{c_n z}$ is an absolutely convergent series for some $z_1, \ldots, z_k$. Show that the series is absolutely convergent for any $z$ in the convex hull of $z_1, \ldots, z_k$.

ATTEMPT: Let $z=\sum \alpha_j z_j$ with $0\leq \alpha_j \leq 1$ and $\sum_{j=1}^k\alpha_j=1$. Then we have by Jensen's Inequality that \begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big|a_ne^{c_n\sum_{j=1}^k\alpha_jz_j}\big| & \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big|a_n \sum_{j=1}^k e^{c_n\alpha_jz_j}\big| \\ & \leq \sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big|a_ne^{c_n\alpha_kz_k}\big| \\ &\leq \sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big|a_ne^{c_nz_k}\big| < \infty  \end{align*}

by assumption.

In this proof, which I turned in on a recent qualifying exam, I am not 100% sure whether I applied Jensen's Inequality appropriately, or if all elements in the convex hull of the $z_j$'s are and only are of the type I have written (I did provide justification that $\sum \alpha_j z_j$ are in every convex set, but did not know how to do the other way around). I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow your first inequality myself.  This is how I'd work with your idea:

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | a_n e^{c_n z_j} | = S_j$.  By Jensen's we have that for $\phi_n(x) = e^{c_nx}$ and a r.v. $Z$ s.t. $P(Z = z_j) = \alpha_j$, choosing the $\alpha_j$ so that $E[Z] = z$,

$$ \phi_n(E[Z]) = e^{c_n\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j z_j} \leq \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j e^{c_n z_j} = E[\phi_n(Z)].$$

(This looks a bit different from what you wrote above.)

$$ \begin{array}{rcl} 
\sum_n a_n\phi_n(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | a_n e^{c_nz} | & \leq & \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | a_n \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j e^{c_n z_j} | \\
 & \leq & \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^k |a_n \alpha_j e^{c_n z_j} |\\
 & \leq & \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n e^{c_n z_j}| = \sum_j \alpha_j S_j < \infty.
\end{array} $$

I also am assuming any element $z$ inside the convex hull can be expressed as we both have written, but this is an elementary fact whose proof can likely be found around MSE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - my first inequality was justified with Jensen's, as yours was; it seems moving the $\alpha_j$ was the only difference in our results. I am not quite sure what justifies the movement of the $\alpha_j$ from the power of the exponential in your proof. In my proof, I kept them as exponents, as I figured that was all Jensen's Inequality would allow for me to do.

Comment: Also, I don't quite know what you meant by MSE?

Comment: The placement of the $\alpha_j$ follows from the definition of the expectation value: $E[\phi(Z)] = \sum_j P(Z = z_j)\cdot \phi(z_j) = \sum_j \alpha_j \cdot \phi(z_j)$.  And MSE = Math Stack Exchange :)

Answer (score 0):

The point is that $|\exp(cz)| = \exp(\text{Re}(cz))$ is a convex function of $z$.

Comment: Right. That is my justification for the second to last inequality as $\alpha_j \leq 1$. And since the convexity of this function holds, my "moving the sum down" in the first inequality is justified via Jensen's Inequality, correct?